# Tightening/loosening a screw spins the threaded screw well

Tags: screws, stuck

Not quite home improvement but I don't know who else to turn to.

I installed a monitor into a mount with the wrong screw and now it's stuck. As the screw spins, the metal well that seated the screw into the plastic case, also spins.

The problem is that the design had the screw wells only attached to the case, where as others would have it secured to the guts of the monitor.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You are not totally *screwed*, although you can't use that threaded insert anymore. Can you remove the screw if you press against the "spinny insert" with an awl? If so, can you use a smaller screw that will pass all the way through so you could put a nut and washer on the other side? Can you drill a hole adjacent to that spot and use a self tapping screw? Can you leave it like it is?

Answer (score 1):

Use a one-ended hacksaw and cut the screw (using a screwdriver to keep it from spinning). Once that's done, and you can remove the monitor frame, you'll be able to deal with (or ignore) the remains of the screw and well.

Answer (score 1):

Prying-leverage might help while you unscrew. Slide a flat screw driver or a knife or something slim between whatever those things are (see image). Then unscrew the screw while applying leverage.

How it works- if the friction between the well and the case is (hopefully) higher than the friction holding the screw in the well, then the screw will turn while the well is held by friction against the inner wall of case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the illustration. I've tried jamming a screw driver in there while prying the space open but to no avail. I'll try jamming two screw drivers in there and leaving them there, while I try to unscrew the screw.